# Comparing two int arrays in C

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there a better way to compare two int array in C++.

```
struct integer
{
    int *number;
    int size;
};
```

This is my struct and i have used this comparing function. I found this solution but it looks like bulshit.

```
int BigInteger::biggest(integer number1, integer number2)
{
    int biggest = 0;
    if (number1.size > number2.size)
    {
        biggest = 1;
    }
    else if (number1.size < number2.size)
    {
        biggest = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = number1.size; i >=0 ; --i)
        {
            if (number1.number[i] > number2.number[i])
            {
                biggest = 1;
                return biggest;
            }
            else if (number1.number[i] < number2.number[i])
            {
                biggest = -1;
                return biggest;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return biggest;
}
```

if function turn value as 1 then number1 greater than number2
if function turn value as 0 then number1 equal to number2
if function turn value as -1 then number2 greater than number1

Comment: A reverse for-loop should begin with `number1.size - 1`. But don't you want to loop forward and compare from the first element?

Comment: Instead of doing the loop and comparison yourself, I suggest you use [`memcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp).

Comment: i cant use another lib like string.

Comment: `else { continue; }` and no more instructions, what is it for?

Comment: @RustyX yeaa you are right i forget to fix there.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi yea its not necessary else. thank you

Comment: Please edit the last 3 lines as it is hard to understand what you are asking for (in fact there is no question asked).

Comment: And by "another lib" it includes the *standard* functions that will always be available with any compiler? Is this a school assignment or something similar?

Comment: Also, insteado of `if (number1.size > number2.size) ... ` do it `if (number1.size != number2.size) return number1.size - number2.size;`

Comment: Lastly, if the code is actually working, and you just want a review of your code, then [there's a site for that](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Using `std::vector<int> number` instead of `int *number` makes the `biggest` function at most a 3 line function.

Comment: `memcmp` should work, even though they are not arrays of integers.

Comment: vector using is forbidden unfortunately.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, would that be user code or total code? The total code may be inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not improve anything except, that it's much clearer

```
int BigInteger::biggest(integer number1, integer number2)
{
    if (number1.size != number2.size)
        return number1.size - number2.size;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < number1.size; ++i) {
        if (number1.number[i] == number2.number[i])
            continue;
        return number1.number[i] - number2.number[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This function

- Returns *> 0* then `number1 > number2`
- Returns *< 0* then `number1 < number2`
- And 0 if they are equal

Also, in c++ you can overload operators so implementing > and < should be easy using this code.

Comment: You've forgotten a `return` in the body of the `if`. Apart from this, you have slightly changed the interface: if `number1 > number2` you return a number that is >0, but the OP talked about 1. It might break something.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few small bugs.  You don't need some of this code. It will run slightly faster when it is not part of a class. And with just a bit of modification it will work with `qsort()` (the parameters need to be pointers) (edit: void pointers)

```
struct integer
{
    int *number;
    int size;
}; 

int biggest(const integer &number1, const integer &number2)
{
    int biggest = 0;
    if (number1.size > number2.size)
    {
        biggest = 1;
    }
    else if (number1.size < number2.size)
    {
        biggest = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = number1.size - 1; i >= 0; i--) // or --i, no difference
        {
            if (number1.number[i] > number2.number[i])
            {
                biggest = 1;
                return biggest;
            }
            if (number1.number[i] < number2.number[i])
            {
                biggest = -1;
                return biggest;
            }
            // don't need a continue statement here
        }
    }
    return biggest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `std::mismatch()` function like this:

```
int BigInteger::biggest(integer a, integer b)
{
    if (a.size != b.size)
        return a.size - a.size;
    const auto res = std::mismatch(a.number, a.number + a.size, b.number);
    if (res.first == (a.number + a.size))
        return 0;
    else
        return (*res.first) < (*res.second) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

The name of the function `biggest()` is quite misleading. `compare()` would be much better. Also, if the function's return type would be boolean (true: `a < b`), then you could use `std::lexicographical_compare()`, and the code would much more simpler.